# mysql how to find the leaf node according to the pid

Tags: mysql

MYSQL how to find the leaf node according to the parent id;

[here is my database data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mY62.png)

[the structure :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjADv.png)

the ouput is: [44069604,44069605,4406960101,4406960102]
and the input is:440696

Comment: Show what parts you can do. Also you are not clear, xplain yourself. That includes connecting your "structure" to your "data". Please read & act on [mcve]. Don't use images/links when you can use text (including for tables & code). Explain what you have googled & tried. Especially since whatever you mean in detail it is going to be a faq.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select pnumber,campus_number from yourTable where pnumber = 440696 and  campus_number not in(44069601)
```

if you want this output only then:

```
where campus_number in (44069604,44069605,4406960101,4406960102)
```

Comment: this is not I want ,the input value is 440696 ,not 44069601

Comment: Sorry don't understand what you mean.. try to update your question from above. try to show your expected output. Maybe it could help your problem.

Comment: I have updated the question.Who else doesn't understand?

Comment: the input value only 440696 ,just one